# Flutter efficient image loading at runtime

Tags: image, flutter

I am trying to add a dice feature to my Flutter application. In Java, I would generate a random number out of 20, and then pull up the corresponding image based on the result.   For example a roll of 14 would pull up an image of dice_image_14.jpg.

I am not sure how to do this in Flutter due to the way build methods work.

The only way I can think to do this is a massive ugly pile of nested conditional statements:

```
@override
build(Buildcontext context) {
  Stack (
    diceRoll == 1 ?
      Container(
        BoxDecoration(
          image: ('lib/images/dice_image_1.jpg),
        ),
      ) : diecroll == 2?
      Container(
        BoxDecoration(
          image: ('lib/images/dice_image_2.jpg),
        ),
      ) : diecroll == 3?  // etc etc etc.   20 times!!
  );
}
```

Is there a more realistic solution for loading specific images into a container on demand post runtime?

Comment: Or..you could separate UI layer and logic layer and return whatever image filename from logic layer and load it on screen.

Answer (score 2):

Just interpolate your `diceRoll` with your asset path:

```
BoxDecoration(
          image: ('lib/images/dice_image_$diceRoll.jpg)
     )
```

From [Dart docs](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour)

> $variableName (or ${expression})
>
> String interpolation: including a variable or expression’s
> string equivalent inside of a string literal.